# How many British men and women were serving in the Boer War at the time of the 1901 census?

Tags: census-records, military-records, united-kingdom, statistics

I have several young men and women who I cannot trace on the British 1901 census, despite numerous and extensive efforts. While there are a number of reasons why I might not be able to find them, one that I have not yet ruled out is that they were serving in the military abroad.

At the time of the 1901 census, the [Second Boer War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Boer_War) (1899-1902) was near its height.

**How many (or what percentage of) British men and women were serving in the Boer War at the time of the 1901 census**, and are therefore not enumerated on that census? Should I consider it likely that a missing woman on the 1901 census may have been a nurse or otherwise serving in the Boer War? Any additional demographic data (age, occupation, etc.) about those serving in the Boer War would be a bonus.

Comment: @JanMurphy linked in chat to some British Army List publications at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/nlsarmylists). The 1901 edition is there. It might contain some helpful information regarding numbers and deployments for (approximately) the right date. Example from a randomly selected page: the Duke of Wellington's West Riding Regiment had the 1st Battalion in SA and the 2nd in Burma.

Comment: Not an answer, but http://britisharmynurses.com/index.php/researching-army-nurses/boer-war-database suggests that the number of British women nusring in the Boer wall was quite small; if you can't identify a person definitevily, I'd be doubtful it was a valid explanation.